# How to convert values of a table into fields in the resultant table of LEFT join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need some help with SQL query. I've no experience with structured DB like SQL. I've been googling this but not getting a proper answer. I've three main tables:

Table1:

```sql
+----+---------+-----+
| id |  name   | age |
+----+---------+-----+
|  1 | Tarun   |  23 |
|  2 | John    |  26 |
|  3 | Rita    |  22 |
|  4 | George  |  28 |
|  5 | Mira    |  25 |
|  6 | Jessica |  27 |
|  7 | Robert  |  24 |
+----+---------+-----+
```

Table2:

```sql
+----+--------+
| id |  sex   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | male   |
|  3 | female |
|  5 | female |
|  6 | female |
|  7 | male   |
+----+--------+
```

Devices:

```sql
+----+-------------+
| id |   device    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | spo2        |
|  5 | thermometer |
|  6 | spo2        |
|  7 | BPmachine   |
+----+-------------+
```

I want to join them and create a CustomTable in such a way that the values of Device column becomes the field name in the final CustomTable and values are set TRUE or FALSE accordingly:

CustomTable

```sql
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| id |  name   |  sex   | spo2  | thermometer | BPmachine |
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Tarun   | male   | TRUE  | FALSE       | FALSE     |
|  5 | Mira    | female | FALSE | TRUE        | FALSE     |
|  6 | Jessica | female | TRUE  | FALSE       | FALSE     |
|  7 | Robert  | male   | FALSE | FALSE       | TRUE      |
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+-----------+
```

Here is the incomplete query that I'm trying:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id as id, 
    t1.name as name, 
    t2.sex as sex, 
    d.device as device 
FROM 
    Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON d.id = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN ??????????
```

I'm sorry for posting a messed up query. That's why I need your help. Please help me.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: But why would gender be in a separate table!?!?

Comment: I would love to do that. But my tech lead will never agree to that. And also many other teams are dependent upon this resultant table.

Comment: @Strawberry, this is not even actual table/data. I just quickly created a dummy one to make my question clear.

Comment: So see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and forget about the gender table, because it's not actually relevant to your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use below mysql statement.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      
       'MAX(IF(t3.id = f.id && t3.device=''',device,''', ''TRUE'', ''FALSE'')) AS ',device
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM TABLE3 t3;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT f.*, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM (SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t2.sex 
FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN TABLE2  t2 ON t1.id=t2.id) f
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON f.id=t3.id
GROUP BY f.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```